# ¿Cómo hace esto chart js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy aprendiendo a usar la librería de chartjs y me surgió una duda, y es que no se como hace la librería para saber que datos corresponden a cual label como en la imagen 1, lo que quiero es poder contar todas las veces que se repiten, por ejemplo en el caso de la imagen me muestra que hay 3 datos que corresponden a algo que yo denomino como dato 3 en mi label1 el cual es P1.

Pongo otra imagen en la que muestra que hay 2 datos en dato:1, quisiera saber como hace al librería para saber esto ya que necesito poder contar cada que estos se repiten tal cual lo muestran las imágenes en cuyo caso la imagen uno pues el contador seria de 3 y en la imagen 2 seria de 2.

Anexo el código que tengo hasta el momento aunque creo que no es relevante, ya que con saber como hace la librería ese proceso me basta para implementarlo de la forma en la que lo necesito.

[image: imagen1]
[image: imagen2]
[image: imagen3]

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
$.ajax({
    //Importar archivos como CSV cambiar para que la persona seleccione el archivo correspondiente
    url: 'RespuestasC.csv',
    dataType: "text",
    contentType: "charset-utf-8"
}).done(grafica);

    function grafica(data) 
    {       
            /* recibe los Datos del excel y los muestra en consola*/
            //console.log(data);
            //quitar saltos de linea
            var Datos= data.split(/\r?\n|\r/); /* pone los Datos del excel en un lista*/
            
            
            

           
            
            var DatosPreguntas = [];
            var Preguntas =[];
            var DatosPorColumna = [];
            var TodasLasRespuestas = [];

            //CICLO PARA SACAR PREGUNTAS CON I=0 TRAE LA PREGUNTA 
            //SinMarca es uan variable que estoy utilizando para omitir la primera columna de los datos del excel puesto que es algo que genera google con la fecha de la respuestas, cuyo dato no necesito 
            for(var i=0; i < Datos.length-1 ;i++){
                
                var DatosSinComas= Datos[i].split(';');
                var SinMarca = DatosSinComas.splice(1);//Para que comienze a mostrar Datos apartir del valor 1 en el arreglo ya que el primero es una marca que no nos sirve
                

                Preguntas.push(SinMarca);
                
            
        }

            //CICLO PARA SACAR PREGUNTAS CON I=0 TRAE LA PREGUNTA Y SUS RESPUESTAS CON I=1 SOLO LAS RESPUESTAS 
            for(var i=1; i < Datos.length-1 ;i++){
                
                var DatosSinComas= Datos[i].split(';');
                var SinMarca = DatosSinComas.splice(1);

                DatosPreguntas.push(SinMarca);
            
        }

      
        //RESPUESTAS DE 1 SOLA FILA (OSEA 1 SOLA PREGUNTA)----Con esto analizar el tamaño de los circulos
       

        for(var i=1; i < Datos.length-1 ;i++){
                
            var DatosSinComas= Datos[i].split(';');
            var SinMarca = DatosSinComas.splice(1).shift();
            DatosPorColumna.push(SinMarca);
      
            }

            // DatosPreguntas es un arreglo bidimensional, con lo cual si queremos leer cada uno de los Datos, toca convertirlo en unidimensional de la siguiente manera
            function ConvertirArreglo2D_en_1D (){
                for(var i = 0; i < DatosPreguntas.length; i++)
                {
                    TodasLasRespuestas = TodasLasRespuestas.concat(DatosPreguntas[i]);
                }
            }
            //Aqui es donde quiero tratar de hacer que cada circulo tenga un radio dependiendo de las respuestas que se repitan

            function adjustRadiusBasedOnData(ctx) {
                var v = ctx.dataset.data[ctx.datasetIndex.size];
                
                return v < 2 ? 30
                    : v < 3 ? 70
                    : v < 4 ? 20
                    : 30;
            }

           

        ConvertirArreglo2D_en_1D(TodasLasRespuestas);


                                //Configuracion de la grafica
                    var config = {
                        type: 'radar',
                        data: {
                            //Aqui toca hacer que lea los Datos de la primera fila ignorando la primera y ultima posicion ya que por defecto genera un ultimo dato vacio
                            labels: Preguntas[0] ,
          
                            datasets: [{

                                label: 'Dato',
                                borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0)",
                                pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255,255, 0)", //color de relleno de los puntos
                                
                               
                    
                                radius: adjustRadiusBasedOnData,
                                borderWidth:2,
                                pointBorderColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
                                pointHoverRadius:adjustRadiusBasedOnData,
                                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)" ,

                                 data: TodasLasRespuestas
                            },]
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Anillos de frecuencia'
                            },

                            scale: {
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    maxTicksLimit:3,
                                    display:false
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        
                    };
                        
                            window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), config);
                        
                        var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);    
                    }   

            });
```

Comment: Hola Miguel, espero estes bien!.. podrias dentro de tu codigo ordenar las variables declaradas ya que hay algunas que empiezan con mayusculas y otras no.  ejemplo: "sinMarca", "datosPorColumna". Abrazos!

Comment: Hola Ricardo, ya ordene las variables, adicionalmente agregue una imagen del Excel que estoy exportando como csv para que se entienda mejor lo que estoy realizando.